# How to add transparent effect to <p:megaMenu> in primefaces?

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

below is my jsf page (code in the body), and the css file:
JSF Page:

```
<h:body id="board">
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <p:megaMenu id="headerMenu">
            <p:submenu label="Video Lessons" styleClass="subMenu">
                <p:column styleClass="headerColumn">
                    <p:submenu label="Instruments">
                        <p:menuitem value="Learn to play the Piano" styleClass="item"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Learn to play the Cello" styleClass="item"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:column>

                <p:column styleClass="headerColumn">
                    <p:submenu label="Theory">
                        <p:menuitem value="Western music history" styleClass="item"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:column>
            </p:submenu>

            <p:submenu label="Teachers" styleClass="subMenu">
                <p:column styleClass="headerColumn">
                    <p:submenu label="Piano">
                        <p:menuitem value="Tamara"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:column>

                <p:column styleClass="headerColumn">
                    <p:submenu label="Guitar">
                        <p:menuitem value="Farzad Daneshmand"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:column>
            </p:submenu>

            <p:submenu label="Instruments" styleClass="subMenu">
                <p:column styleClass="headerColumn">
                    <p:submenu label="Strings">
                        <p:menuitem value="Cello"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:column>

                <p:column styleClass="headerColumn">
                    <p:submenu label="Keyboards">
                        <p:menuitem value="Organ"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:column>
            </p:submenu>

            <p:menuitem value="About us" styleClass="item"/>
        </p:megaMenu>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

css file(homeStyle.css):

```
#headerMenu {
    background-color: rgba(88,56,32,0);
}
#board {
    background-image: url("images/sheetmusic.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

in the css part i try to make the megaMenu transparent and it works fine, but there are two problems:

1.When hovering on the menu subMenus, i.e. Video lessons, Teachers,... , blue highlight still exists.

2.When opening a new sub menu the css is not applied to the subMenus, so when i try to add below code to the css it doesn't work like what i expected in the megaMenu:

```
.headerColumn {
    background-color: rgba(88,56,32,0);
}
```

but changing the '0' to '1' in the rgba() makes a solid brown, which is not what i want; besides, it only applys to the inner part of the column.

and one more thing, the output in the InternetExplorer does not work like what it's supposed to be.
here is what i get in google chrome (works fine in chrome):
[image]
any suggestions?
thansks!

Comment: cant recreated your problem in a fiddle, can you create a demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add opacity to the css of the menu child as shown below:

```
.ui-menu.ui-megamenu .ui-menu-parent .ui-menu-child {
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help, the texts inside of the menu are gonna be transparent as well.